# Unit testing with Karma on an Angular 1.3/JSPM/Babel project

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, ecmascript-6, jspm

So I'm setting up an angular 1.3 es6 project using jspm and babel. Im using es6's import/export feature. I have karma and karma-jspm installed and can run basic tests without an issue. When I try to import one of my modules into a test to test it, I get an error in karma.

`Error loading "app/services/chart-data/chart-data.spec" at http://localhost:9876/base/app/services/chart-data/chart-data.spec.js
Error loading "npm:babel-core@5.3.3" at http://localhost:9876/base/jspm_packages/npm/babel-core@5.3.3.js
Error evaluating http://localhost:9876/base/jspm_packages/npm/babel-core@5.3.3.js
Error evaluating http://localhost:9876/base/jspm_packages/npm/babel-core@5.3.3/browser.js
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 're.test.bind(re)')
at undefined`

And here is a piece of my karma config file:

```
frameworks: ['jspm', 'jasmine'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
],

jspm: {
  // Edit this to your needs
  loadFiles: ['app/**/*.spec.js'],
  serveFiles: []
},
```

And this is an example test:

```
import {chartData} from 'chart-data.service';

describe('Example test', function() {
  it('should be foo', function() {
      expect('foo').toBe('foo');
  });
});
```

I haven't had any luck with searching for an answer and even asked for help in the jspm gitter, but nothings turned out so far.

Everything else in the project seems to work fine, and I can run the test if I remove the import line. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are running tests in browser which doesn't support [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). Babel needs this function.

You can fix is by [karma-phantomjs-shim](https://github.com/tschaub/karma-phantomjs-shim), or try a new version of browser. Since version 2.0, PhantomJS has this function.

Comment: Perfect. That fixed the babel issue, thanks! I have a couple more issues (not sure if I should ask a new question or I can do it here). First issue is karma keeps looking at my bower components dir (it's in app/components) which has a bunch of bootstrap js files and it keeps failing on it. I don't want it to load those. 

When I get rid of the bootstrap dir it works fine, but then it mentions it can't find angular. When I explicitly add angular to the load files (under the jspm object) it says angular got loaded more than once.

Again, lemme know if I should just create new questions.

Thanks!

Comment: You `app/componetns` directory is affected by your wildcard expression in jspm configuration. If you should move bower components out of this directory, or change jspm config and make it more specific